# What are the best preset build option for use with firebase-hosting and polymer 1.x

Tags: polymer, firebase-hosting

In Polymer CLI, there are currently 3 preset build options, namely `es5-bundled`, `es6-bundled`, `es6-unbundled`.

I would like to know what are the best preset build for use with firebase-hosting for PWA (Polymer 1.x) in terms of network delivery and compatibility with different mobile browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation from Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/build-for-production):

> Static hosting services like **GitHub Pages** and **Firebase Hosting** don't
>   support serving different files to different user agents. If you're
>   hosting your application on one of these services, you'll need to
>   serve a **single build**.
>
> If you're serving a single build to all browsers and you need to
>   support browsers that don't support ES6, such as IE11 and Safari 9,
>   then this build needs to be compiled to ES5:
>
> `polymer build --js-compile`

If you have Safari or IE users then, the best build preset option will be `es5-bundled`. Bundled because not all browsers support HTTP/2 push.

**es5-bundled:**

```
name: es5-bundled
js: {minify: true, compile: true}
css: {minify: true}
html: {minify: true}
bundle: true
addServiceWorker: true
addPushManifest: true
insertPrefetchLinks: true
```

Comment: There is a good video from the Polymer team 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByV3MWTa1fw

Comment: For modern mobile devices, the option would be `es6-unbundled`